# Vectors initialised in member initialisation list not the same as passed to constructor..?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple table class which contains two vectors initialised with a member initialisation list:

**Table.hh**

```cpp
class Table
{
public:
    Table(vector<double> a, vector<double> b);
    ~Table();

    double interpolate(double val, bool extrapolate = true);
    double integrate();

    void print();

private:
    vector<double> x, y;

};
```

**Table.cc**

```cpp
Table::Table(vector<double> a, vector<double> b)
: x(a), y(b)
{
    cout << this->x.size() << " " << this->y.size() << endl;

    try
    {
        if (this->x.size() != this->y.size())
            throw LengthException();
    }   
    catch(exception &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

When I try to test out the exception by creating a new instance of Table:

```cpp
vector<double> a = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
vector<double> b = {1.0, 2,0, 3.0};

Table* mytable = new Table(a, b);
```

i'm finding that the exception does not get thrown and that the size of each vector is given as 4.

I can't immediately see why this is not working as expected, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the size of vector `b` is 4:

I reformatted your code and now it should be obvious:

```
vector<double> b = { 1.0,
                     2,
                     0,
                     3.0 };
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I didn't spot that!

Comment: @Ron TBH: I first ran it through the debugger which showed immediately that `b.size()` was 4.